# Is it better to store data locally or load from the web

Tags: java, android

I am looking to make an Android wallpapers app and searching more information to how to build it:

- If a user does not have an SD card in their device then where should I store the wallpaper?
- Is it better to store wallpapers locally or download them from the web?

Comment: I think, if the user don't have an sdcard, ha have a big memory in his phone so you can use the local storage.

Comment: Generally if you can store something locally its good because its less the person has to download over the web so faster application and it uses less of their usage quota. In your case thought storing a heap of wall papers, people aren't going to like their app taking up loads of space on their phone. I know I wouldn't, so id just download them from the web.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the wallpapers locally:

- No data connection required
- Faster access
- No network programming
- Not as dynamic. If you wanted to add new wallpapers later, you would have to update the entire application

Storing the wallpapers remotely:

- Data connection required
- Slower access
- Network programming required
- Dynamic. New wallpapers can be downloaded on the fly

The current paradigm is to display a 'wallpaper browser' to the user so the user can select which wallpapers he/she wants to download from the internet and then save those wallpapers locally.

The issue of whether a user has an SD-card or not doesn't matter so much. If they have an SD-card, save the wallpapers on to the SD-card. If they don't, save the wallpapers to the phone's internal memory.